# Why will my y value not show up on my graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I actually cannot seem to figure out why my `y` value will not show up on the graph. This is a much simpler graph than ones that I have done in the past, yet I seem to be struggling with this. What could be the reason that the `y` value won't show up?

When I change the value of `y`, the limits of the graph change accordingly but the value is still missing.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i75490483/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What value are you not seeing? There are labels on the gradients of your y axis.

Comment: the `y` plot needs a `marker` since it's only 1 point: `ax.plot(0, y, marker='o')` (by default it draws lines, so there's no line with only 1 point)

Comment: or `ax.scatter(0, y)` will work without manually setting `marker` since it plots points by default

Answer (score 0):

replace `ax.plot(0, y)` with replace `ax.plot(0, y, marker='o')`
Since (0, 2.5) is an infinitely small point, you need to give it a marker so it's visible.